# Bash - CP difficulties

Tags: 11.04, command-line, bash

cp -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_2.0.2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/

That command is making this: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/codeigniter_2.0.2` and I need only the content of codeigniter_2.0.2 inside test.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cp -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_2.0.2/* /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/
```

Comment: If there are hidden file, it is better to use the syntax `cp /from/path/. /to/path`

Comment: I have tried using * but some files inside codeigniter_2.0.2 where not copied, only the folders

Comment: @enzotib that dot made the difference =) thanks

Answer (score 0):

here's a workaround

```
cp -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_2.0.2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/temp && mv /opt/lampp/htdocs/temp/codeigniter_2.0.2/* /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/ && rm -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/temp
```

that's assuming Sergey's answer doesn't work, because if it does it isn't unnecessarily complicated like mine :D